# kubernetes not able to pull images from private docker registry

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I want to create a customized docker image and be able to use kubernetes to pull my customized docker image from private docker registry. Here are my setups:

Environment:
docker registry ip:10.179.143.115
kubernetes master ip: 10.179.143.113

1. generate a certificate:

> ```
> curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/driskell/log-courier/1.x/src/lc-tlscert/lc-tlscert.go
>
> go build lc-tlscert.go
>
> ./lc-tlscert
>
> mkdir certs
>
> mv selfsigned.* certs/
> ```

2. Create docker registry:

> docker run -d   --restart=always   --name registry   -v
>   `pwd`/certs:/certs   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443   -e
>   REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/selfsigned.crt   -e
>   REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/selfsigned.key   -p 443:443   registry:2

3. Create my customized docker vm(just tag the vm with another name for testing purpose)

> ```
> docker pull tomcat
>
> docker tag tomcat 10.179.143.115/test-tomcat
>
> docker push 10.179.143.115/test-tomcat
> ```

4. On Kubernetes master:

> ```
> copy selfsigned.*(crt and key file)  to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
>
> sudo update-ca-certificates
>
> sudo service docker restart
> ```
>
> root@kubernetes-master:~# docker images
>
> ```
> REPOSITORY                                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
> gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64            v1.9.3              360d55f91cbf        3 weeks ago         210 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/kube-controller-manager-amd64   v1.9.3              83dbda6ee810        3 weeks ago         138 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/kube-proxy-amd64                v1.9.3              35fdc6da5fd8        3 weeks ago         109 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/kube-scheduler-amd64            v1.9.3              d3534b539b76        3 weeks ago         62.7 MB
> quay.io/coreos/flannel                                   v0.10.0-amd64       f0fad859c909        5 weeks ago         44.6 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64                      3.1.11              59d36f27cceb        2 months ago        194 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64           1.14.7              db76ee297b85        4 months ago        42 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64          1.14.7              5d049a8c4eec        4 months ago        50.3 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64     1.14.7              5feec37454f4        4 months ago        41 MB
> gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64                     3.0                 99e59f495ffa        22 months ago       747 kB
>
> root@kubernetes-master:~# docker pull 10.179.143.115/test-tomcat
> Using default tag: latest
> latest: Pulling from test-tomcat
> f0f063e89695: Pull complete
> d9b7671d4a80: Pull complete
> 6eb55822688c: Pull complete
> a85cc2721f25: Pull complete
> ee9e2e7b610a: Pull complete
> 562dd1fb5637: Pull complete
> e8e2e3cceeee: Pull complete
> 86cbf3cde839: Pull complete
> 3678522c43a2: Pull complete
> 50ea7ae5efa3: Pull complete
> e81b257a8ae8: Pull complete
> 5b298dc937bc: Pull complete
> Digest: sha256:332fa1b89534f0b0e45c636a26edb8520b15bcdfc05ef5450efae3e71d1b1361
> Status: Downloaded newer image for 10.179.143.115/test-tomcat:latest
> ```

5.However, when I want to create a kubernete pod:

> ```
>  test.yaml: 
>     apiVersion: v1 
>     kind: Pod 
>     metadata:   
>     name: test 
>     spec:  
>     containers:
>       - name: test
>         image: 10.179.143.115/test-tomcat
> ```

```
kubectl create -f test.yaml

root@kubernetes-master:~# kubectl describe pods test

Name:         test
Namespace:    default
Node:         kubernetes-node/10.179.143.114
Start Time:   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 15:02:20 -0500
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:
Containers:
  test:
    Container ID:
    Image:          10.179.143.115/test-tomcat
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ErrImagePull
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-lvz9r (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-lvz9r:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-lvz9r
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From                      Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----                      -------
  Normal   Scheduled              32s               default-scheduler         Successfully assigned test to kubernetes-node
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  31s               kubelet, kubernetes-node  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-lvz9r"
  Normal   Pulling                9s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet, kubernetes-node  pulling image "10.179.143.115/test-tomcat"
  Warning  Failed                 9s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet, kubernetes-node  Failed to pull image "10.179.143.115/test-tomcat": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://10.179.143.115/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed                 9s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet, kubernetes-node  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   SandboxChanged         9s (x2 over 20s)  kubelet, kubernetes-node  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

6.Error message is :

```
Failed to pull image "10.179.143.115/test-tomcat": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://10.179.143.115/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Plesase bear with my bad formatting and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help guys! Here is a follow up on how I make it works.

When I copy all the certs to kubenetes master, I am able to pull and push docker images from my private registry. But it was not working when I want to create kubernetes pods. And I realized that I need also to copy all the certs to my kubernetes slave and that is the place where kubernetes actually pull the images from private docker registry. After I copy the certs to "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/" and run "sudo update-ca-certificates; sudo service docker restart" , I am able to create pods now!

Answer (score -1):

In my understanding, a Secret resource has to be created to use the private docker registry. Refer [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-in-the-cluster-that-holds-your-authorization-token)!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But when I create docker registry, I do not set any restricting access to the docker registry. Here is the [link](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#restricting-access) I am referring to. Do I have to setup an authentication?

Comment: The error you're seeing is because the docker daemon not being able to login to the private registry because the cert it's using in unsigned. Have a look here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the cert is unsigned, and I have put my cert in kubernetes master and run the "update-ca-certificates". That should solve the cert issue and I am able to do "docker push". But I am still not able to start the image from Kubernetes.

Comment: There are two options I can think of, though neither might be direct answer to your problem. First option, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006832/unable-to-pull-image-from-quay-io-error-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-aut#comment61592112_37006832. Second, try if using    --insecure-registry    helps in your case. In my case, insecure-registry entries were added in docker-sysconfig.conf and image pull from private repo by kubernetes just worked fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I found where the problem is. My setup is a two-node kubernetes cluster and I only update the cert on kubernetes master, however, the kubernetes slave should also be updated. That also explains why I could do a docker pull and push from the master.